# Word in office 2007 and Windows 7 ultimate cant navigate to folders

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2007

In word 2007 I click office button top left I click open, I get the open box, in the top address bar, I if I click on the down arrow far right (previous Locations) the drop down menu is empty just a box with nothing in it. To go anywhere from here I have to navigate via the left had pane, on all other windows systems this dropdown has enabled me to go to any location on my computer. I'm wondering if because all my word documents are on my D drive that windows 7 doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

The open dialog shows the last location used by the application, however if the last location is no longer available (Removable media or other device), it usually just defaults to your home/my documents directory.

Something sounds like it has gone seriously wrong.

Go to an elevated command prompt and type `SFC /SCANNOW`, If this doesn't fix it, go to the `Start Orb` and click `All Programs` and then `Microsoft Office`. Next, expand `Tools` and launch `Microsoft Office Diagnostics` and see if that helps.

If this finds nothing, go to `Programs and Features` and do a repair install of Microsoft Office.

Please write in comments if any of this helps and/or any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 7 version of that dropdown is different than previous versions of Windows.

It's the "previous locations" sub system, and it's tied to all open/save dialogs and Explorer windows, etc.  In previous versions that dropdown arrow would just give you a file structure (Desktop, My Computer, My Network Places, C: , D:, etc.)

The weird thing about it (that takes some getting used to) is it only adds locations to it if you type them into the bar to navigate (exclusivly using the mouse to click your way someplace won't add it to that dropdown, but using a combination of typing into the address bar and then mousing around *does* seem to add it though).

So if you type "D:\" into the bar that dropdown arrow is attached to (the address bar) and then hit enter it will navigate you to the root of D: and "D:\" will be in that dropdown list next time you look.

The list is dynamic, and the most used/typed locations will bubble to the top over time.